# how to share internet connection from wireless to wired using bridge on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, bridge

I have two machine. I need share the internet from one to another.

Machine 1 with two adapter.

OS: WINDOWS 7

WIRELESS NETWORK ADAPTER has connected to Internet. There is no share tab for this adapter.

WIRED NETWORK ADAPTER

Machine 2 with one adapter.

WIRED NETWORK ADAPTER

Two machine is connected by wired network adapter.

I want to create bridge on MACHINE 1 between wireless and wired adapters. I just created bridge by default. Bridge is created succefully. I did nothing MACHIINE 2 for now. Two adapter on MACHINE 1 are all connected succefully to bridge. But MACHINE 1 is failed to connect to internet. And Bridge is getting error which is not be configured IP. I did not configured IP for all adapters. They all get ip by DHCP by default. I am confused, since there are solutions which said that it is no need to configured anything. Does anyone have similar experience?

Comment: Consider you may need a different cable connecting two computers directly. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: There is no need to use crossover(568A-568B) cable for now. Well, I am confused about that MACHINE 1 cant connect to internet.